# Paho MQTT in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, telerik, mqtt, nativescript

I'm trying to use the Poho MQTT library's JavaScript implementation (http://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js) in a NativeScript application.

I referenced the file with `require("./lib/mqttws31");` and replaced all the `window.timer`'s with `require("timer")` statements. I also added `require("nativescript-websockets");`to the top of the mqttws31.js file after installing the module from github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-websockets. I also commented out the bit of code referring to `localstorage`.

I'm getting the application to run, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: That's a browser based library - so it probably has a lot of dependency on browser specific APIs/elements which won't work with NativeScript since there is now window or DOM to work with. Native apps don't have DOM.

Comment: Thanks. NativeScript is starting to get frustrating. Anytime I want to anything slightly complex I run into problems with it not supporting something.

Comment: Understandable. It's frustrating when things don't work as you expect. Just want to make sure you understand my comment. Do you understand my point about not having DOM or window and any browser API? Once you understand that this is a native app things become easier in my opinion. Hence the power of NativeScript, no DOM.

Comment: Yes I understand that there is no DOM. What would be nice is if Telerik would provide proper documentation on creating plugins with a few examples explaining advanced concepts. I have used the blog post by Nathanael which has helped a bit but it explains a very basic library.

Comment: @MorneZaayman did you find solution. I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you are better off using the webview with [nativescript webview interface](https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-webview-interface-demo)
 for bidirectional control between webpage and nativescript it's more like an advanced ionic or should we say Cordova app